# Flutter Flick video player not playing device's videos

Tags: flutter

I was using [flick video player](https://pub.dev/packages/flick_video_player#:%7E:text=Flick%20Video%20Player-,Flick%20Video%20Player%20is%20a%20video%20player%20for%20flutter.,set%20of%20UI%20and%20functionalities.) package in flutter but it works on network videos & not on device videos, even though path stated is correct.

Error message:

> Unexpected error1: 'package:flutter/src/services/message_codec.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 111 pos 15: 'code != null': is not true.

Code:

```
 @override
      void initState() {
        secure();
        print(widget.video.path);
        super.initState();
        flickManager = FlickManager(
            videoPlayerController: widget.video != null
                ? VideoPlayerController.network(widget.videoLink)
                : VideoPlayerController.file(
                    File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/K2app/1603884177002/no.mp4"))
              ..addListener(() {
                print("added");
                setState(() {});
              })
              ..initialize().then((value) {
                print('initialized listener');
                setState(() {});
              }).catchError((error) {
                print('Unexpected error1: $error');
              }));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it on the web, then this is still an open issue.
The Web platform does not support dart:io, so attempts to create a VideoPlayerController.file will throw an UnimplementedError.

Please check this below link.
https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better. Also, provide a basic coverage of the content of your link, in case it stops working in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your code snippet on android device and I was able to play video.
Although, when I tried to play a `.mov` video format it ran in some exception.

I see you are trying to play a `.mp4` video , can you try with the latest version, `flick_video_player: ^0.3.1` and check if you are still getting this error.